# Optimization network speed using Java

Tags: java, networking

There are two directories (local and remote). The directories is synchronized. I don't want to slow down the network. I want to use a dynamic limit to the speed. So, I should determine network speed (for upload).

How to determine network speed (for upload)?
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved. I want to determine network speed transiently and I want to use a dynamic limit to the speed (ex: %50 less) for each upload files (or download files) . For example; if my upload speed 100kb per second, it should be 50kb per second dynamically, if it is 150kb per second, it should be 75kb per second dynamically.

So, I upload first package of my files and determine `bytes per second`. It is my upload speed. Then, I determine my dynamic limit (limit = myUploadSpeed %50). Then, calculate sleep duration `(sleep_duration=((myUploadSpeed-limit)/limit)*1000)` (there is 1000 to convert from milisecond to second) . `if (limit>bytesPerSecond)` for each packet sent to the next , wait until `sleep_duration`

My code to throttle as follows:

```
private void throttle() throws IOException {
      long limit= calculateMaxBytesPerSecond();
      long bytePerSec= getBytesPerSec();
    if (limit!=-1 && bytePerSec > limit) {

        long sleep_duration=((bytePerSec-limit)/limit)*1000;

      try {
          if(sleep_duration==0)
              Thread.sleep(1000);
          else
              Thread.sleep(sleep_duration);

        totalSleepTime += SLEEP_DURATION_MS;
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new IOException("Thread aborted", e);
      }
    }
  }

private long calculateMaxBytesPerSecond() {
      switch (streamType) {
    case 0:
        if(connectionManager.getDownloadSpeedLimit()>0)
            return connectionManager.getDownloadSpeedLimit() / downloadManager.getTaskCount();
        else
            return -1;

    case 1:
        if(connectionManager.getUploadSpeedLimit()>0)
            return connectionManager.getUploadSpeedLimit() / uploadManager.getTaskCount();
        else
            return -1;
    }

    return Long.MAX_VALUE;
  }

public long getBytesPerSec() {
    long elapsed = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000;
    if (elapsed == 0) {
      return bytesRead;
    } else {
      return bytesRead / elapsed;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send X MB per second, send X MB and if it has been less than a second, wait until the end of the second.  To determine how much you are sending, keep a counter whenever you send data.